# Cumulative wealth calculation with return and outflow without for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

Suppose I have a starting wealth of $100 and returns of 2%, 1%, -1%, 0.5%. Also I have an expense of $2 at every time point. I want to calculate accumulated wealth at each time point. I can do this in the following way.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

r = np.array([100, 0.02, 0.01, -0.01, 0.005])

def wealth(rs, out = 2):
    # rs : (initial wealth, return) array, (n+1) x 1
    # w : wealth is calculated iteratively
    # annual outflow : 2
    return list(itertools.accumulate(rs, lambda w,r: w*(1+r)-out))

wealth(r)
```

It returns

```
[100.0, 100.0, 99.0, 96.01, 94.49005]
```

So far it works. Now suppose outflow/expense is not constant, but different at each time step. For example, it could be a predetermined array of expenses, or inflate by 2% every time, so that my new expenses are

```
np.array([2*((1 + 0.02)**n) for n in range(len(r)-1)]).round(3)
[2.   , 2.04 , 2.081, 2.122]
```

What I want here is the following :
`100*(1 + r) - outflow`,
where outflow now is `[2.   , 2.04 , 2.081, 2.122]`. In previous case it was a constant, 2. In the new case, the solution would be

```
[100, 100, 98.96, 97.9092, 98.3675]
```

How do I incorporate that?

Update :
Many of you asked why can I not use for-loop. Here are some context. Instead of one set of returns, I want to simulate 100,000. Consider the following.

```
N = 100000
n = 40
r = np.array(np.random.normal(0.05, 0.14, N*n)).reshape((N, n))
rm0 = np.insert(rm, 0, 100, axis=1)
result = np.apply_along_axis(wealth, 1, rm0) # N wealth paths are created

import pandas as pd
allWealth = pd.DataFrame(result.T, columns=range(N), index=range(n+1))
```

This runs fast. For-loop was taking really long. Hence my desire to avoid for loop.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what formula you're trying to calculate or what your inputs look like.

Comment: Edited. See if this makes sense.

Comment: Why do you have a restriction of not using a `for` loop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - In my case, r, the return matrix is n*m, where n = 100,000 and m = 40. And I have to do this for 10 different instances. For loop was taking way to long to run.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop a very easier solution to use here

```
def wealth(rs, out):
    result = [rs[0]]
    for r, o in zip(rs[1:], out):
        result.append(result[-1] * (1 + r) - o)
    return result
```

And it seems the result quite differs : `[100.0, 100.0, 98.96, 95.8894, 94.24684]`

---

The `accumulate` version isn't very nice

```
def wealth(rs, out):
    fct = lambda prv, val: (prv[0] * (1 + val[0]) - out[prv[1]], prv[1] + 1)
    return [x[0] for x in itertools.accumulate(zip(rs, range(len(rs))), fct)]
```

Comment: 100*1.01*.99-2*1.02*1.02 = 97.9092. Not sure why you are getting 95.8894